# Pure CSS flyout menu - show/hide on tap/touch/click

Tags: css

I am trying to modify a CSS only menu that implements a horizontal flyout. The original code does it on hover. I am trying to achieve the same thing on touch/tap - that is: tap once to show it, tap again to close it.

Is this possible using pure CSS ?

I've inserted the code below, but please refer to the codepen - it renders better. The challenge I am facing is right now I have to keep it pressed for the menu to show - how do I toggle without using javascript?

The codepen: http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/WwPgwg

```css
/*
Forked from http://codepen.io/IanLunn/pen/NPapxy */
/*
 sass flyout.scss >flyout.css (sudo gem install sass)
 or sass flyout.scss --style compressed >flyout.min.css
 "IL" logo Copyright (c) Ian Lunn Design Limited 2015

 Modified by pliable pixels
*/
.drawer {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  /*height: 100%;*/
  padding: .4em 0;
  background: #7D294E;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  /* Remove 4px gap between <li> */
  font-size: 0;
}
.drawer li {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  list-style: none;
  transform: translateZ(0);
}
.drawer a {
  pointer-events: auto;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  min-width: 5em;
  margin-bottom: .4em;
  padding: .4em;
  line-height: 100%;
  /* Reset font-size */
  font-size: 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  transition: background 0.2s;
}
.drawer a:active, .drawer a:focus {
  background: #B44659;
}
.drawer i {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: .2em;
  font-size: 2em;
}
.drawer span {
  font-size: .625em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.drawer li:active ul {
  /* Open the fly-out menu */
  transform: translateX(0);
  background: #B44659;
  /* Enable this if you wish to replicate hoverIntent */
}
.drawer > li {
  display: block;
  /* Fly out menus */
}
.drawer > li > a {
  background: #7D294E;
}
.drawer > li:active, .drawer > li:focus {
  z-index: 100;
}
.drawer > li:active, .drawer > li:focus a {
  background: #B44659;
}
.drawer > li a:active {
  background: #F56356;
}
.drawer > li ul {
  position: absolute;
  /* Stack below the top level */
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  /* height: 100%;*/
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Close the menus */
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  background: #B44659;
  transition: 0.2s transform;
}
```

```html
<ul class="drawer">
        <li>
            <a href="">
               
                <span>Info</span>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.google.com">
                        
                        <span>Item 1</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.google.com" >
                        
                        <span>Item 2</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://www.google.com">
                        
                        <span>Item 3</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Use a checkbox and a label and :checked pseudoclass. Or try your best with the :target pseudoclass.

Comment: Here's an example using checkboxes for a pure CSS toggle http://clearleft.com/thinks/260

Comment: Thank you - so it looks like the checkbox hack is the way to go. I'm struggling trying to figure out how to fit that into the effect of the codepen I posted (I'm rather unfamiliar with pseudo classes). I'd appreciate if you could get me started on how to implement the checkbox hack into the codepen I posted.

Comment: I used @jamez example and created this jsfiddle: [css flyout menu](https://jsfiddle.net/jaspercreel/rfvg5mcg/). Does this help?

Comment: @JamesHamann - getting close thank you very much! http://codepen.io/pliablepixels/pen/yOZGmN --> a) How do I make sure the blue sub menu perfectly aligns with the red button b) A small gap between each list item (horizontal) c) That is slides in exactly after the red button stops (no matter how wide the text is in the red button)?

Comment: a) Do you mean line up as in vertically? I would just give the #flyout-menu div a "top:(some number)px" value to push it down the correct amount. b) You can add padding-right or margin-right to the list items to create space between them, and then eliminate that space on the li:last-child. C) Sorry, I am not sure what you mean by this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following code, that should work for you.

```
<a href="#something">Show</a>
<div id="something">Bingo!</div>
```

CSS:

```
#something {
  display: none;
}

#something:target {
  display: block;
}
```

Heres a codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EKreRy

Comment: Does that close it when tapped again?

Comment: Unfortunately not. For that you would need to use the checkbook method mentioned previously.

Comment: That is one of the requirements so this doesn't completely answering the question..

Answer (score 0):

The following code work for me

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
       <a href="#something" id='target'>Show</a>
       <div id="something">Bingo!<a href="#target">hide</a></div>
       <style>
           #something {display: none;}
           #something:target {display: block;}
           #target:target #something{display: none;}
    </style>
</div>
</body>
```